# Passing a vector to a function

Tags: c++, vector, openssl

I have the following code. It works fine when I use arrays, I just want to refactor it with vectors so I can reduce the footprint of my hashes.

```
uint8_t* rip(uint8_t *in, vector<uint8_t*> *out)
{
    RIPEMD160(in, 32, out);
    return out;
}

int main()
{
    char pub_key[] = "0450863AD64A87AE8A2FE83C1AF1A8403CB53F53E486D8511DAD8A04887E5B23522CD470243453A299FA9E77237716103ABC11A1DF38855ED6F2EE187E9C582BA6";
    vector<uint8_t> res_rip(20);
    uint8_t res_sha[32];
    uint8_t res_tmp[65];
    hex_decode(pub_key,131,res_tmp);
    for(int i =0; i < 65; i++)
        cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hex << (int)res_tmp[i];
    cout << endl << endl;
    sha(res_tmp,res_sha);
    rip(res_sha,&res_rip);
    for(int i =0; i < 32; i++)
        cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hex << (int)res_sha[i];
    cout << endl << endl;
    for(int i =0; i < 20; i++)
        cout << setw(2) << setfill('0') << hex << (int)res_rip[i];
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not sure how I need to pass the vector to the function, or what I need to do to properly return it.

I get compiler message `error: cannot convert 'std::vector<unsigned char*>*' to 'unsigned char*' for argument '3' to 'unsigned char* RIPEMD160(const unsigned char*, size_t, unsigned char*)'`

Comment: What line gives that error message?

Comment: Also, you're passing `vector<uint8_t>*` to function that expects `vector<uint8_t*>*`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That function expects a pointer to the data, not a `std::vector`.

In C++11, you can get a pointer to the data in a vector by calling [`std::vector::data()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data).

```
RIPEMD160(in, 32, out->data() );
```

In C++03 or later, you can get a pointer to the data in a vector by taking the address of the first element.

```
RIPEMD160(in, 32, &out->at(0) );
```

Comment: Isn't vector::data() part of C++11?
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data

Comment: @lucasmrod You are correct.  There seems to be a fuzzy transition at SO now where C++11 can be assumed unless the question specifies that an answer should work in older standards.

Comment: Almost there : `out` is currently a pointer to a vector , not a vector, so you code is faulty.  Suggest replacing pointer with (const?) reference, and you get +1 from me!

Comment: @Roddy Thanks for catching that.